# iOS SubView with Custom Delegate

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates, subview

I have three viewControllers, a tableViewController that adds a subView on touching a cell, let's call this the userSubView, which is viewController 2. Hitting a button on VC2 adds another subView let's call actionSubView, which is VC3.

I need an action on VC3 to call a required delegate protocol method on VC1. VC1 imports the custom delegate in the header file and Xcode correctly populates the required method on VC1. I also set the delegate to self in VC1 after instantiating VC3 in VC1.

However, my delegate method isn't called. What about subViews would cause this? Is there something conceptually I'm missing in using self. It's a ton of code to post because of all the VC's, and I think there's a basic idea I'm missing with nested subViews and delegates.

Thanks, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Eric as you talk about ViewControllers ,Do you push them on stack or just add their views onto a Main View i.e are your table view , userSubView and actionView added on same view as subviews ?

Comment: @RahulSharma yes they are on the same View, I just dim the alpha on the previous view each time. They are all separate view controllers but added as subViews.

Answer (score 0):

Message passing between multiple Objects (View objects or View Controller objects) is essentially the same way.

In the problem statement above I could find no reason to take three UIViewController subclasses just to use their views to be used for adding as subviews on a parent view. The very same purpose could also be solved by taking UIView subclasses.

I took three UIView subclasses , all of which have required delegate methods to implement in the calling class. The Main View Controller will have their declaration like

```
#import "FirstView.h"
#import "SecondView.h"
#import "ThirdView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ItemPickerDelegate , AllowLoadDelegate>
{
    FirstView*      objFirstView;
    SecondView*     objSecondView;
    ThirdView*      objThirdView;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain)  FirstView*      objFirstView;
@property (nonatomic , retain)  SecondView*     objSecondView;
@property (nonatomic , retain)  ThirdView*      objThirdView;

@end
```

Now the Implementation for the same View Controller subclass will look something like

```
@implementation ViewController


@synthesize objFirstView;
@synthesize objSecondView;
@synthesize objThirdView;


-(void)dealloc {
    [objFirstView release];
    [objSecondView release];
    [objThirdView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadInitialView];
}

-(void)loadInitialView {
    if (!objFirstView) {
        self.objFirstView = [FirstView initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.objFirstView setCaller:self];
    [self.objFirstView setCurrentContentMode:TableContentModeAll];
    [self.view addSubview:objFirstView];

    [objFirstView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 220)];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark -Delegate From First View

- (void)didSelectTableView:(UITableView*)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (objSecondView) {
        [objSecondView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else if (!objSecondView) {
        self.objSecondView = [SecondView initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.objSecondView setCaller:self];
    [self.view addSubview:objSecondView];
    [objSecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 220, 320,60)];
}
- (void)didApplyFilter:(TableContentMode)filter {
    NSLog(@"%d filter Loaded",filter);
}

#pragma mark -Delegate From Second View

- (void)didAllowLoadFilters:(BOOL)allow {
    if (objThirdView) {
        [objThirdView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else if (!objThirdView) {
        self.objThirdView = [ThirdView initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.objThirdView setCaller:objFirstView];
    [self.view addSubview:objThirdView];
    [objThirdView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 320,30)];

}

@end
```

The simplest way to call a required delegate method of First View from third view is mentioned in the very last delegate method implementation of Second View.

```
[self.objThirdView setCaller:objFirstView];
```

The flow goes as Follows:

Main ViewController (MainVC) adds subview of FirstView -> FirstView loads a TableView -> When a TableCell is selected -> Delegate method is called in MainVC. This calls for adding Second view as Subview. SecondView displays a button -> Button tapped (call to delegate method in MainVC for adding subview of Third View. Now ThirdView displays a Segment control -> segment control value changed - > FirstView table is reloaded according to selected Filter and one of required delegate methods of FirstView is called in MainVC.

I know the answer is a self explanatory (bit lengthy :-) though) but if your still have any issues you can check the source code from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/33943536/MessagePassingDemo.zip) and take reference from.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(UIViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).callMethod
```

where 1 is the number of controller in the stack you want to access